# Redux seems to be getting state/reducers mixed up

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm having a really strange issue in react in which my reducers seem to be modifying parts of the state that they shouldn't, I'm sure this is due to some oversight in my implementation, but I can't track it down.

I currently have one store, two actions/action creators, two reducers, and one root reducer. Here is my code, (left out some unimportant details):

```
//actionTypes.ts

export const SUBMIT_SEARCH = "SUBMIT_SEARCH";
export const CHANGE_SEARCH_PAGE = "CHANGE_SEARCH_PAGE";
```

-

```
//actionCreators.ts

import { SUBMIT_SEARCH, CHANGE_SEARCH_PAGE } from "./actionTypes"

export const submitSearch = (submitSearch) => ({
    type: SUBMIT_SEARCH,
    submitSearch
});

export const changeSearchPage = (changeSearchPage) => ({
    type: CHANGE_SEARCH_PAGE,
    changeSearchPage
});
```

-

```
//submitSearchReducer.ts

import { SUBMIT_SEARCH } from "../actions/actionTypes";

const submitSearch = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
    case SUBMIT_SEARCH:
        return {
            ...state,
            submitSearch: action.submitSearch
        }
    default:
        return state;
    };
};

export default submitSearch;
```

-

```
//changeSearchPageReducer.ts

import { CHANGE_SEARCH_PAGE } from "../actions/actionTypes";

const changeSearchPage = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CHANGE_SEARCH_PAGE:
            return {
                ...state,
                changeSearchPage: action.changeSearchPage
            }
        default:
            return state;
    };
};

export default changeSearchPage;
```

-

```
//rootReducer.ts

import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import submitSearch from "../reducers/submitSearchReducer"
import changeSearchPage from "../reducers/submitSearchReducer";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    submitSearch: submitSearch,
    changeSearchPage: changeSearchPage
});

export default rootReducer;
```

-

I create the store like this:

```
const logger = createLogger();
const store: Store<any> = createStore(rootReducer, {/*Initial state empty*/}, applyMiddleware(logger));
```

-

The general flow is like this:

- User enters a search string on the page which triggers a `store.dispatch(submitSearch(string))` call
- User enters a number on the page which triggers a `store.dispatch(changeSearchPage(newPage))`

Here's the output from my logger:

[![Search call][1]][1]
[![change page call][2]][2]

You can see here that the state is clearly getting mixed up, and the wrong data is going to the changeSearchPage key.

What is causing this mix up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the rootReducer you're importing the same reducer twice

Comment: @JavascriptLoser, accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: This is a good reason to avoid default exports and use `import { changeSearchPage } from "../reducers/changeSearchPage"` - you'll get an explicit error.